# Rails, devise: how to replace previous login via token authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, replace, devise

I use devise with module `TokenAuthentication`

And it is ok when I unauthenticated and I follow link with ?auth_token= part. Like this:

I follow link: `/orders?auth_token=q2a8w6virARzv6B2C1vR` where `q2a8w6virARzv6B2C1vR` is authentication_token of **user1**. And now I logged in as **user1**.

But when I logged in as some user via email\password and common sign_in page and then follow such link with auth_token with another user token I unexpectedly stay logged in as first user.

Like this:

1. I sign in via sign in page. I
   fill in email and password of **user2**.
   And now I logged in as **user2**
2. I follow link:
       `/orders?auth_token=q2a8w6virARzv6B2C1vR`
       where `q2a8w6virARzv6B2C1vR` is
       authentication_token of **user1**. And I
       still logged in as **user2** instead of
       expected **user1**.

Is it bug? And what is the best practices to change this behavior to force replace authentication via token?

Rails 3.0.6

Devise 1.2.1

Answer (score 2):

you did uncomment  :token_authenticatable in your user model, correct?

Comment: Yes, of course I uncommented `:token_authenticatable` in user model

Answer (score 2):

Let's do some question necromancy...

Before running stragegies (token_authenticatable, database_authenticatable) Warden first checks if user is already set in current session.

This happens in: https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/3d653371a2ff594d9965c1dde642c98cd8485e15/lib/warden/proxy.rb#L212

Is action responding /orders query supposed to use *only* token auth? If so, you can add: `before_filter: reset_session` (before `authorize_user`) so that Warden failed to unserialize user from the session and was forced to perform authentication.

[EDIT]
This issue ticket contains reasonable solution: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1644